# How do I pass a method into a variable that takes a closure?

Tags: swift

I have a framework where I have an editable tableViewCell. One of its properties are onChangeHandler declared as

```
var onChangeHandler: ((String) -> Void)? { get set }
```

I'd like to use this as validation on different input types and would also like to write the code  clean and easily readable.

This code works:

```
        textFieldCell.placeholder.text = "E-mail"
        textFieldCell.onChangeHandler = { email in
            if email.contains("@") {
                self.email = email
                textFieldCell.validationMessage?.removeAll()
        } else {
            textFieldCell.validationMessage = "Email not valid"
            } }
```

But what I want is to isolate the above code in a separate method, like this, but I don't know if it is possible to return the validationMessage somehow?

```
        textFieldCell.placeholder.text = "E-mail"
        textFieldCell.onChangeHandler = { email in self.validateEmail(email) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that functions are *named closures*, so you can set a function directly to `onChangeHandler`:

```
textFieldCell.placeholder.text = "E-mail"
textFieldCell.onChangeHandler = validate(email:)

func validate(email: String) {
    if email.contains("@") {
        self.email = email
        textFieldCell.validationMessage?.removeAll()
    } else {
        textFieldCell.validationMessage = "Email not valid"
    }
}
```

<sub>**Sidebar Note**: this is not how you should validate the email, probably you will need to use a regular expression.</sub>

Since `validate` function has the same signature of `onChangeHandler` which is "it takes a string and returns void" it should be valid.

At this point, I'd assume `textFieldCell` is declared where it could be accessible in the `validate` function.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense! But the cell is not available inside the function, and it doesn't seem to be possible get the value in it. The way it is used in simpler terms is like this:
   textFieldCell.onChangeHandler = { newValue in self.firstName = newValue }

I used email as example, but I see I need to use newValue, but that is not accessible unless used in closure I think?

And since the cell is not available inside the function, I think I should return a String from the function?